# Area of asymmetric lens by integration?

Tags: integration, geometry

[image]

The blue region above is called an *asymmetric lens*.

Both small circles have radius 1, both large circles have radius 2, and the (four) circles are at center separation $r$.

The area of the blue region is given by an integral of arc lengths: 
$$
\int_{r-1}^{2} 2 x \arccos\left(\frac{x^2 + r^2 - 1}{2 r x}\right) \, dx
$$
moving from left to right. Integration by parts gives this (blue area) as
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(8 \sec ^{-1}\left(\frac{4 r}{r^2+3}\right)-\sqrt{-r^4+10 r^2-9}-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{r^2-3}{\sqrt{-r^4+10 r^2-9}}\right)+\pi \right)
$$
but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Split by the line between the corners and use the formula for the circular segment.

Comment: The area is what it is, and integration by parts _is_ elegant. Do you want another formula?

Comment: This formula may simplify?

Comment: @Yves What is the "line between the corners"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the area of two segments.
[image]

Comment: So this red line is the area between the corners I see.

Comment: @AlexanderGiles, yes they are the intersection points.

Comment: OK thanks this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\theta_l-\sin\theta_l}2r_l^2+\frac{\theta_r-\sin\theta_r}2r_r^2,$$

where

$$\cos\frac{\theta_l}2=\frac{d^2-r_r^2+r_l^2}{2d},\cos\frac{\theta_r}2=\frac{d^2-r_l^2+r_r^2}{2d}.$$

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to integrate a function over this region, so this helps.